# iOS get exc-bad -access at -> CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why do I get exc-bad-access at `CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook)`?

How to release iPhoneAddressBook variable?

This is my code

```
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook;

iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(iPhoneAddressBook,  ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error){
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
});

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

CFErrorRef error;

[self CheckIfGroupExistWithName:@"group name"];

ABRecordRef group = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(iPhoneAddressBook, self->groupId);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);
//Create new person and save to this group
ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
BOOL isSuccess ;
ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(@"name"), nil);

isSuccess = ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, record, &error);
isSuccess = ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);

ABGroupAddMember(group, record, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);
CFRelease(record);
CFRelease(group);
CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);
```

This the NSZombie log:

```
0    Malloc +1  1   00:29.823.269   AppSupport  _createInstance
1    CFRetain   +1  2   00:29.823.360   AppSupport  CPRecordLoadHandler
2    CFRelease  -1  1   00:29.823.365   AppSupport  CPRecordLoadHandler
3    CFRetain   +1  2   00:29.823.452   AppSupport  CPRecordLoadHandler
4    CFRelease  -1  1   00:29.823.507   AppSupport  _loadInstanceFromDB
21   CFRetain   +1  2   00:30.326.335   AddressBook ABCRecordSetValueAndReturnError
24   CFRetain   +1  3   00:30.328.305   AppSupport  _createRecordsArrayFromDictionary
25   CFRelease  -1  2   00:30.328.460   AddressBook ABCAddressBookSaveWithConflictPolicy
28   CFRelease  -1  1   00:30.339.684   AppSupport  CPRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType
29   CFRelease  -1  0   00:30.764.433   DigiPharma  -[SpeakerProfileViewController addToContacts:]
30  Zombie      -1  00:30.764.698   AppSupport  CPRecordStoreDestroy
```

Comment: Could you try running your app with NSZombieEnabled . Google how to do this if you don't know how. Then post the resulting log and I'll help.

Comment: u r releasing the object,and the app is crashing bcz some object is still using the `iPhoneAddressBook` get the code clean,release it only when we work is done

Comment: What muku said, some point in your app you are trying to access the iphoneAddressBook and it doesn't exist, if it's crashing at this point it means that iphoneaddressbook is nil maybe it was never created ?

Comment: thats what im saying let him put NSZombie and we might get a clue as to where it is.

Comment: @Maro, have you tried implement all that logic (after `dispatch_semaphore_wait`) inside of `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` completion block? Just before `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);`.

Answer (score 2):

Th crucial line is

```
CFRelease(group);
```

`ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID` does not contain `create` nor `copy` so there is no need to release the object.

Solution: delete the line.

From the Core Foundation Memory Management documentation:

> **The Get Rule**
>   If you receive an object from any Core Foundation function other than
>   a creation or copy function—such as a Get function—you do not own it
>   and cannot be certain of the object’s life span. If you want to ensure
>   that such an object is not disposed of while you are using it, you
>   must claim ownership (with the CFRetain function). You are then
>   responsible for relinquishing ownership when you have finished with
>   it.

Comment: You meant `CFRelease(group);`?